# Getting seconds from a timer function to my view

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views

I want to get the minutes and seconds from the timer in my template to my view.

I already tried different approaches with an ajax.post request but it didnt really work how I wanted it to be.

Here is my template:

```
{% block content %}

    <!-- Timer function -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var sec = 0;
        function pad ( val ) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
        setInterval( function(){
            $("#seconds").html(pad(++sec%60));
            $("#minutes").html(pad(parseInt(sec/60,10)));
        }, 1000);
    </script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <span id="minutes"></span>:<span id="seconds"></span>

  <form action="results" id=results method="POST">

    <!-- after clicking on this button the minutes and seconds should also be sent as a POST request -->

    <div class="command">
      <button type="submit" name="ctest_submit">Submit solution</button>
    </div>

  </form>


{% endblock %}
```

Now I want to get the minutes and seconds to my view as a POST request after clicking on the submit button. My idea was it to hide the time in a input like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="seconds" value="what should be in here???">
```

but I dont know what should be in value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fill the input values inside your interval.
Give your inputs ids (let's say `#seconds-input` & `#minutes-input`), and use

`$('#minutes-input').val(pad(parseInt(sec/60,10))`, 
and `$('#seconds-input').val(pad(++sec%60)` inside the interval.

Even better, save the seconds and minutes as vars and then assign them to both spans and inputs.

Comment: I tried giving the inputs an id with this <input type="hidden" name="seconds" id="seconds"> and using the id in my timer function, but the number isnt showing anymore and after clicking on submit the seconds are somehow empty?

Comment: And about your second method, how do I call the vars in my html?